# Use a variable to access key in struct

Tags: struct, solidity

I have a struct like so :

```
struct test {
    string a;
    string b;
}
```

and a mapping like this:

```
mapping (address => test) public tests;
```

I want to have a function to update the struct like this:

```
function updateStruct (string _paramName, string _newValue) {
  tests[msg.sender].(_paramName) = _newValue; // this is the line that shows the logic but doesn't work in compilation
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solidity currently (v0.8) does not support accessing properties via magic variables.

You'll need to access the properties directly.

```
function updateStructA(string memory _newValue) public {
    tests[msg.sender].a = _newValue;
}

function updateStructB(string memory _newValue) public {
    tests[msg.sender].b = _newValue;
}
```